# jQuery to remove a button from footer navbar

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jQueryMobile 1.4.5, I need to toggle the presence of the middle button on and off so that the other 2 buttons butt_up against each other if the middle button is gone.
My js script makes it disappear but leaves room between the ouster 2 buttons.
How can this be achieved?  Thanks

[image]

```js
jQuery.fn.invisible = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
};

jQuery.fn.visibilityToggle = function() {
    return this.css('visibility', function(i, visibility) {
        return (visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
};

$("li:nth-child(2)").invisible();
```

```html
      <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
               <li><button type="submit" data-theme="c">NO</button></li>
               <li><button type="submit" data-theme="c">EXTRA</button></li>
               <li><button type="submit" data-theme="c">YES</button></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </footer><!-- footer -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no jqm method to refresh a navbar. Hopefully we get one with 1.5 ...

But you can manipulate the "grid classes" of the navbar.
I think this is the easiest way if you only want to add/remove one button.

```js
 $('#toggle').on("click", function() {
   if ($("#navbar > ul").hasClass('ui-grid-b')) {
     $("#extra").hide();
     $("#navbar > ul").removeClass('ui-grid-b').addClass('ui-grid-a')
       .find("li").last().removeClass('ui-block-c').addClass("ui-block-b");
   } else {
     $("#extra").show();
     $("#navbar > ul").removeClass('ui-grid-a').addClass('ui-grid-b')
       .find("li").last().removeClass('ui-block-b').addClass("ui-block-c");
   }
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>


<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="submit" data-theme="c">NO</button>
      </li>
      <li id="extra">
        <button type="submit" data-theme="c">EXTRA</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="submit" data-theme="c">YES</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- footer -->
```